# Add serial number to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add serial number to a textview in android recyclerview. But it throws the below error

My code is here

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RViewHolder holder,final int position) {
            final commdtylist listitem=listitems2.get(position);
            for(i=1;i<=listitems2.size();i++){
                holder.comm_code.setText(i);
            }
```

Comment: in for loop define int i=1

Comment: @angelina If you only need serial number use holder.getAdapterPosition() why you have used the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`setText();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(char[],%20int,%20int)) method required  **`String`** value as a parameter not **`int`**  value

Use this

```
holder.comm_code.setText(i+"");
```

OR this

```
 holder.comm_code.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

Instead of this

```
holder.comm_code.setText(i);
```

**EDIT**

```
   holder.comm_code.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        final commdtylist listitem=listitems2.get(position);
        for(i=1;i<=listitems2.size();i++){
            holder.comm_code.setText(i);
        }
        }
```

Use

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        final commdtylist listitem=listitems2.get(position);
            holder.comm_code.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
      }
```

Comment: only last value printing

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
 holder.comm_code.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
```

Comment: only last value printing , value is constant in every textview

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        final commdtylist listitem=listitems2.get(position);
        String str = "";
        for(i=1;i<=listitems2.size();i++){
            str = TextUtils.concat(str,String.valueOf(i)," ").toString();
        }
        holder.comm_code.setText(str);
    }
```

Comment: only last value printing

Comment: @angelina,Check it

Answer (score 1):

Their is a mistake in for loop add `int i = 1`.

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RViewHolder holder,final int position) {
            final commdtylist listitem=listitems2.get(position);
            for(int i=1;i<=listitems2.size();i++){
                holder.comm_code.setText(""+position);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are right but when you scroll up and down the numbering of top view and bottom view changes, since recycle view recycles the view that are not there on screen.
To overcome that issue simply write:

//The code is in Kotlin

```
val number = (position+1)%(itemList.size+1)
    holder.comm_code.text = number.toString()
```

the itemList is the list that you will pass in recyclerAdapter class.
Basically your position is increasing but the final answer will always be less than and equal to your list size.

Comment: this code is very useful.... thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you are displaying list in textview its simple just add a textview to show position before the item in layout eg :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_info"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvholdRank"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Centre Name : "
                android:textColor="@color/safety_orange"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>
```

than in apdater get textview id:

```
tvCenterRank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCenterRank);
```

than set it as :

```
tvCenterRank.setText(String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()+1));
```

dont forget to add +1 since the counting starts with 0